# Template specialization of a method

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [template class member function only specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949992/template-class-member-function-only-specialization)
>   [If I want to specialise just one method in a template, how do I do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330561/if-i-want-to-specialise-just-one-method-in-a-template-how-do-i-do-it)

Today a colleague demonstrated this form of specialization to me (compiled with GCC):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
struct Item {
    Item(const T & value) : value(value) {}

    std::string toString() const {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << value;
        return ss.str();
    }

    T value;
};


template<>
std::string Item<char>::toString() const {
    return "I am a character.";
}


int main() {
    Item<int> i(1);
    std::cout << "i: " << i.toString() << std::endl;

    Item<char> c('c');
    std::cout << "c: " << c.toString() << std::endl;
}
```

I always thought there was only class specialization (full or partial) and function specialization.

Is the above standard C++? If yes, then what is the name of this kind of specialization?

#### Update

[Looks like this question has been answered before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949992/template-class-member-function-only-specialization)

Answer (score 0):

It's standard c++.
This is template specialization.In the case you just specialize a method, it's called partial template specialization.
Also, look [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of *explicit specialization*. If there was still a template parameter (but fewer than originally) it would be *partial specialization*.