# specialize friend operator in template class previously defined error

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword, friend

I tried to specialize << operator for char in my template class

hpp

```
template<class T>
class tablicowy{
public:
    T * tablica;
    int rozmiar;
public:
    tablicowy(T arr[], int n){
        {
            tablica = arr;
            rozmiar = n;
        }
    };
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, tablicowy<char>& that );
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, tablicowy<T>& that ){
        out << "( ";
        for(int i = 0; i < that.rozmiar; i++){
            out << that.tablica[i] << comma;
        }
        out << ")";
        return out;
    };

};
```

cpp

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, tablicowy<char>& that ){
    out << "'";
    for(int i = 0; i < that.rozmiar; i++){
        out << that.tablica[i];
    }
    out << "'";
    return out;
};
```

C++ give me :

> In file included from
>   /home/pawel/ClionProjects/lista9/obliczenia.cpp:1:0:
>   /home/pawel/ClionProjects/lista9/obliczenia.hpp: In instantiation of
>   ‘class obliczenia::tablicowy’:
>   /home/pawel/ClionProjects/lista9/obliczenia.cpp:38:28:   required from
>   here /home/pawel/ClionProjects/lista9/obliczenia.hpp:40:30: error:
>   redefinition of ‘std::ostream& obliczenia::operator<<(std::ostream&,
>   obliczenia::tablicowy&)’
>            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, tablicowy& that ){
>                                 ^ /home/pawel/ClionProjects/lista9/obliczenia.cpp:36:15: error:
>   ‘std::ostream& obliczenia::operator<<(std::ostream&,
>   obliczenia::tablicowy&)’ previously defined here  std::ostream&
>   operator<<(std::ostream& out, tablicowy& that ){

What can i do to overload or specialize that operator for char?

Comment: See these two threads:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949992/template-class-member-function-only-specialization][1]


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330561/if-i-want-to-specialise-just-one-method-in-a-template-how-do-i-do-it/9330636#9330636][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949992/template-class-member-function-only-specialization
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330561/if-i-want-to-specialise-just-one-method-in-a-template-how-do-i-do-it/9330636#9330636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
// Forward declare the class
template <typename T> class tablicowy;

// Forward declare the template operator
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, tablicowy<T>& that );

// Forward declare the function
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, tablicowy<char>& that );

// Your class:
template<class T>
class tablicowy{
public:
    T * tablica;
    int rozmiar;
public:
    tablicowy(T arr[], int n){
        {
            tablica = arr;
            rozmiar = n;
        }
    };
    // just declare them friend.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, tablicowy<char>& that );
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream& out, tablicowy<T>& that );

};

// Implementation
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, tablicowy<T>& that )
{
    const std::string comma = ",";
    out << "( ";
    for(int i = 0; i < that.rozmiar; i++){
        out << that.tablica[i] << comma;
    }
    out << ")";
    return out;
}
```

And in cpp:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, tablicowy<char>& that ){
    out << "'";
    for(int i = 0; i < that.rozmiar; i++){
        out << that.tablica[i];
    }
    out << "'";
    return out;
}
```

[https://ideone.com/SXClzp](Live example)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `template <>` before `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, tablicowy<char>& that );` to indicate it is a Template Specialization

You will also need to move implementation of friend class outside of class - see [Explicit specialization of friend function for a class template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464064/explicit-specialization-of-friend-function-for-a-class-template) for details

Comment: when i added this:
error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class obliczenia::tablicowy<T>’
         template <>
                   ^
/home/pawel/ClionProjects/lista9/obliczenia.hpp: In instantiation of ‘class obliczenia::tablicowy<char>’:

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464064/explicit-specialization-of-friend-function-for-a-class-template