# destructor implementation in templated class

Tags: c++, class, templates, destructor, delete-operator

If I have a class like this:

```
template <class T>                            
class Array {                                              
 private:                                        
  T *m_pData;                                   
  unsigned int m_nSize;                         
 public:                                         
 Array(unsigned int nSize) : m_nSize(nSize),m_pData(nullptr) {                                           
 if(m_nSize > 0)
  m_pData = new T[m_nSize];                
 }                                           

 ~Array() {                    
  if(m_pData != NULL) {
   delete [] m_pData;
  }
};
```

If now I create an object of my class like this:

```
Array<int> miArray(5);
```

Implementation of the destructor should be fine, but if I create an object like this:

```
Array<int*> miArray(5);
```

In the destructor I should delete every object stored in the array to avoid memory leaks.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to allocate memory for every pointer in your array, you will have to change the constructor too, I guess. You will have to specialize your class.

Comment: [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii), [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: use smart pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [a specialization of your destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5950287/3233393), or tag-dispatch to a deletion function (which would be more flexible). However, this leads to a pretty awkward and brittle design. Supposing you have implemented an equivalent to `push_back`, consider these user code snippets:

```
{
    Array<int*> arr;
    arr.push_back(new int(42)); // new is on the side of the user
} // ... but delete is not. Weird.
```

This also leads to a whole class of errors: you sohuld only give `new`ed `T`s to an `Array<T*>`, but there is no security whatsoever against passing in something else:

```
{
    Array<int*> arr;
    int i = 42;
    arr.push_back(&i); // No diagnostic
    arr.push_back(new int[17]); // No diagnostic either
} // Undefined behaviour from calling `delete` on stuff that hasn't been `new`ed
```

All of this is the reason for the existence of the *No raw owning pointers* rule: raw pointers should not manage resource lifetime, at all. If I use an `Array<int*>`, it should store my pointers and let me use them, but never *ever* `delete` them, because that's trying to manage lifetime.

Instead, if I want an `Array` that manages lifetime, I'll use the corresponding smart pointer, with `Array<std::unique_ptr<int>>`. This ties in nicely with `Array`, requiring it to only call the destructor of the contained objects (which it already does). These destructors (`~unique_ptr`, that is) will transitively deallocate the resources as is their job, and all is well.

### Additional notes:

- Take care to initialize your `Array`'s buffer if you need -- `m_pData = new T[m_nSize];` will allocate default-initialized objects. If these objects have no default constructor, their value will be indeterminate. A simple fix is to use `new T[m_nSize]{}`, which will perform value-initialization -- that is, initialize arithmetic types to zero, pointers to `nullptr`, and compound types recursively.
- Implement copy and/or move semantics for your class, see [*Rule of three/five/zero*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). As it is now, copying an instance of `Array` will lead to two instances thinking they own the same buffer, and undefined behaviour when both try to `delete` it.
- `delete` and `delete` check for null, so the `if(m_pData != NULL)` in the destructor is redundant.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

I think a good design would be to just wrap raw *owning* pointers (e.g. `int*` in your example) in *smart* pointer classes, like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, or some other RAII wrapper. 
This is what basically happens with `std::vector`, where you can have `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` or `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` if you want to store owning pointers to T in the vector.

Note that storing raw *observing* pointers in your container is fine (as far as the life-time of the pointed objects is properly taken care of).

---

Just a couple of additional notes:

1. Your class should either ban copy via `=delete` copy constructor and copy assignment, or properly implement these copy operations. As it is in current state, it's bug-prone if people try to copy construct or copy assign instances of your class.
2. `Array(unsigned int nSize)` constructor should be marked `explicit` to avoid *implicit* conversions from unsigned ints.